# Angular ui router html5Mode false and accented URLs in chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, chromium

I always use html5Mode true when using angular ui-router but for a project hosted on github pages, I can't activate this mode given that no server side redirection is possible. So lets go with uggly hashbangs # in URL ;)

My state

```
.state('app.root.elus', {
    url : 'élus',
```

Displays in Chromium Browser URL bar :

```
/#/%C3%A9lus
```

But if I activate html5Mode, the URL displays correctly

```
/#/élus
```

In Firefox, in both modes, accents are correctly displayed ...

Would anybody have a beginning of explanation and solution ?

Comment: Can you mock up a Plunker demo? It doesn't appear to be anything Chrome does automatically

Comment: You can check the page here : http://politiques.lol/#/élus